# How do I take the users input and if it equals 1 it would be day and a 2 would be night?

Tags: python

I am trying to get the user's input and if the enter a 1 for shift it would print out day shift and 2 would equal night shift. I am doing this using object oriented so I do not know really how to do that as I am very new to it. Also, I have read on here that the way I was taught to set up my classes is not the best way to do it for python but that was how the professor wants it so not much I can do about that.

class Employee

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.__name = name
        self.__number = number

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def set_number(self, number):
        self.__number = number

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def get_number(self):
        return self.__number
```

class ProductionWorker

```
import employee

class ProductionWorker(employee.Employee):
    def __init__(self, name, number, shift, pay):
        employee.Employee.__init__(self, name, number)

        self.__shift = shift

        self.__pay = pay

    def set_shift(self, shift):
        self.__shift = shift


    def set_pay(self, pay):
        self.__pay = pay

    def get_shift(self):
        return self.__shift

    def get_pay(self):
        return self.__pay

    def dayNight(self, shift):
        if shift == 1:
            self.__shift = "Day Shift"
        else:
            self.__shift = "Night Shift"

    def __str__(self):
        return "\nName: " + self.get_name() + "\nNumber: " + self.get_number() + \
               "\nShift: " + self.get_shift() + "\nPay: " + self.__pay
```

employeeTest

```
import ProductionWorker


def main():
    name = input("Enter the users name: ")
    number = input("Enter the users number: ")
    shift = input("Enter the users shift (1, 2): ")
    pay = input("Enter the users hourly pay rate: ")    


    employee = ProductionWorker.ProductionWorker(name, number, shift, pay)
    empShift = employee.get_shift()
    print(employee)

main()
```

Comment: Your instructor wouldn't happen to be a Java diehard who's merely dabbling in Python, would they?

Comment: haha I think he might be. No basically I am in an accelerated class and so python is easier for the class to learn but he wants us to have an understanding of how java and c++ languages work so we aren't completely confused if we ever tried to write in those languages.

Comment: That's laudable if one views Python as a kiddy language that serves only as a stepping-stone to real languages, but, if one understands that Python is just as legitimate a language as Java or C++, there's no logical reason to learn one improperly just to prepare for the other.

Comment: Yeah I agree that it shouldn't be used as a stepping stone and since learning python I have come very fond of it.

Comment: It's good to learn Java and C++ for the mental exercise if you're still a student. Many people use these every day for their jobs. I feel sorry for them as it's also possible to make a living as a Python engineer. No need to feel sorry for me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a method called `display_shift` that shows the human-readable shift name as stored in a `dict` property of the static class:

```
class ProductionWorker(employee.Employee):
    SHIFT_NAMES = {
        '1': 'day',
        '2': 'night',
        'W': 'weekend',  # just an example how you could easily add other shifts
    }

    # ...other code...

    def display_shift(self):
        return self.SHIFT_NAMES[self.get_shift()]

# ...init code...

employee = ProductionWorker(name, number, shift, pay)
print(employee.display_shift())  # 'day' or 'night'
```

Alternatives to the static dict `SHIFT_NAMES` are:

- an instance dict set inside the `__init__` as `self.shift_names = {...}`, this would allow for some method like `def add_shift(self, shift_number, shift_name)` to add any new shifts the company may need (overtime? weekend? holiday?)
- a tuple like `SHIFT_NAMES = ('day', 'night')` and `display_shift` like `return self.SHIFT_NAMES[int(self.get_shift()) - 1]`. The benefit of this would be the inability to change or add to the shift names. A drawback would be shifts would need to remain consecutively ordered `int`s and the direct relation between shift number and shift name isn't explicitly clear.
- a separate static class or `collections.namedtuple` are other possibilities

EDIT:

To show the shift when `str(employee)` is called you could use the `__str__` magic method to do something like this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '{}({}, #{}, {} shift, ${}/hr)'.format(
        self.__class__.__name__, self.get_name(), self.get_number(),
        self.display_shift(), self.get_pay())
```

This would result in something like the following:

```
>>> print(employee)
ProductionWorker(John Doe, #12345, day shift, $40/hr)
```

You can [read more about Python magic methods here.](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html)

Comment: Is there a way to display that day or night shift in the str method rather

Comment: I wish I could up vote for you man but it says I cant up vote until I have 15 reputations. But thank you so much for the help

Comment: Hey sorry for being a pain but how would you format that hourly wage to print out two decimal spots like 15.00. I am not sure where to put '.2f'  Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dict mapping shifts to "1" and "2" then do a lookup with the instance shift value.

```
class ProductionWorker(employee.Employee):
    def __init__(self, name, number, shift, pay):
        employee.Employee.__init__(self, name, number)
        self.shifts = {"1":"Day shift","2":"Night shift"}  


def main():
    name = input("Enter the users name: ")
    number = input("Enter the users number: ")
    shift = input("Enter the users shift (1, 2): ")
    pay = input("Enter the users hourly pay rate: ")    


    employee = ProductionWorker.ProductionWorker(name, number, shift, pay)
    empShift = employee.get_shift()
    print(employee)
    print(employee.shifts[empShift])

main()
```

You can use a method if required in your class, the logic will be basically the same.

To print all the details using `__str__` just do the lookup in the `get_shift` method instead of just returning self.__shift:

```
class ProductionWorker.ProductionWorker(Employee):
    def __init__(self, name, number, shift, pay):
         employee.Employee.__init__(self, name, number)
        self.shifts = {"1": "Day shift", "2": "Night shift"}
        self.__shift = shift
        self.__pay = pay

    def set_shift(self, shift):
        self.__shift = shift

    def set_pay(self, pay):
        self.__pay = pay

    def get_shift(self):
        return self.shifts[self.__shift]

    def get_pay(self):
        return self.__pay

    def dayNight(self, shift):
        return self.shifts[shift]

    def __str__(self):
        return "\nName: {}\nNumber: {}\nShift: {}\nPay: {}".\
            format(self.get_name(), self.get_number(), self.dayNight(self.get_shift()), self.__pay)
```

Output:

```
Enter the users name: foo
Enter the users number: 1234
Enter the users shift (1, 2): 2
Enter the users hourly pay rate: 100

Name: foo
Number: 1234
Shift: Night shift
Pay: 100
```

If you wanted to use your DayNight method with an if/else you would have to compare to a string  not an int and the easiest way would just to return the strings:

```
    def set_shift(self, shift):
        self.__shift = shift

    def set_pay(self, pay):
        self.__pay = pay

    def get_shift(self):
        return self.__shift

    def get_pay(self):
        return self.__pay

    def dayNight(self, shift):
        if shift == "1":
            return"Day Shift"
        else:
            return "Night Shift"

    def __str__(self):
        return "\nName: {}\nNumber: {}\nShift: {}\nPay: {}".\
            format(self.get_name(), self.get_number(), self.dayNight(self.get_shift()), self.__pay)
```

Comment: Is there a way to display that day or night shift in the __str__ method rather

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have defined an instance method dayNight in the class ProductionWorker but never used it, either you should modify the difinition and explicitly call it after instantiating the class object like this(also there is no need to pass shift argument):

dayNight definition:

```
    def dayNight(self):
        if self.__shift == 1:
            self.__shift = "Day Shift"
        else:
            self.__shift = "Night Shift"
```

then instantiate like this:

```
    employee = ProductionWorker.ProductionWorker(name, number, shift, pay)
    employee.dayNight()
    print(employee)
```

OR

do this by modifying your **init** only:

```
    def __init__(self, name, number, shift, pay):
        employee.Employee.__init__(self, name, number)
        if shift == 1:
            self.__shift = "Day Shift"
        else:
            self.__shift = "Night Shift"
```

then instantiate like this:

```
    employee = ProductionWorker.ProductionWorker(name, number, shift, pay)
    print(employee)
```

Comment: Thanks I had dayNight instance used but after playing with my code for so long I forgot that I didn't even call it anymore